# How to get "Send Message" button in Facebook Page Post or Image Share via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-messenger

I am trying to automate Post and Shares in Facebook Page's feed using the Graph API.

For simple posts in feed like text and link I was able to do it with no struggle.
(Based in this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed#publish)

Then I got into making a Share of photo or video. Again not a problem. But I have noticed in Facebook Page itself it is possible to add a Send Message button. Where it even has a label with "Add this button to your post so people can reply directly in Messenger."

[Facebook create post in Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbgvw.png)

I was looking in the actions sections and other places and I found no way to add it via Graph request.

Currently, I am generating the Post via Graph like this:

POST graph.facebook.com/v2.10/MY_PAGE_ID/photos?access_token=PAGE_TOKEN&caption=MY_TEXT&url=IMAGE_URL

It it possible to add the Send Message button via Graph? Or this is only restricted to Facebook UI?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if this is available via the API, but have a look at `call_to_action` here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/post

Comment: For my understanding this is directed to reading the post and even so it is intended to adds. For posting, it directs to the /page/feed (also no luck in update the post).
I have also tried checking the `actions` in this node as I said and doesn't seem to have what I want. I suppose this is not open to the Graph. Thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: Hi Fábio Oliveira. Have you found any solutions? I want to create Page Post Ad, but unable to add "Send Message" button with it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @nitin7805. Unfortunately I found no solution for this. My vote is that Graph is not ready for this request. Let me also know if you ever find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this endpoint `/page-id/feed` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/post

***call_to_action*** parameter should be

```
{"type":"MESSAGE_PAGE","value":{}}
```